# Quick sort implementation in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have pasted my implementation of the quicksort algorithm below. After some debugging I figured out that the recursion of the function quicksort() does not seem to terminate. But it seems to me that my algorithm is fine and I am not able to fix the bug.

```
/*
quicksort 
*/
int a[20];
int partition(int left,int right, int*a)
    {
        //chose some pivot element- in this case i choose the middle one
        int pivot=(left+right)/2;
        int b[10],c[10],i=left,j=0;
        int k=0;
        int pivot_element=a[pivot];

        //b is the left side ,c is the right side
        while(i<=right)
        {
            if(a[i]!=pivot_element)
            {
                if(a[i]<a[pivot])
                {
                    b[j++]=a[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    c[k++]=a[i];
                }
            }       
            i++;

        }


        //combine
        i=left;

        for(int q=0;q<j;q++)
        a[i++]=b[q];

        a[i++]=pivot_element;

        for(int p=0;p<k;p++)
        a[i++]=c[p];


        return j; //return the new position of the pivot
    }


    void quicksort(int left,int right,int *a)
    {

        int index=partition(left,right,a);
        if(index-left>0)
        quicksort(left,index,a);
        if(right-index+1>0)
        quicksort(index+1,right,a);

    }


    int main()
    {
        int size;
        cin>>size;
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        cin>>a[i];

        quicksort(0,size-1,a);

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";

        return 0;
    }**
```

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ (Eric Lippert, "How to debug small programs", 2014-03-05).

Comment: Debug and see what is going on. I think `partition` function returns the same number each time

Comment: Also, how many numbers are you trying to sort?  Many times we get posts such as yours, and the reason why the poster can't figure things out is that they're either testing using too many numbers to sort, or the numbers are random thus never get a chance to pin down the issue easily.  Try to sort 5, maybe 6 *known* numbers and follow your code with that.

Comment: You can't be sure that you'll partition the array into equally sized parts.

Comment: `j` is not the new position of the pivot, as it's an index in the "left" array you copied to. The position you return from `partition` must be between `left` and `right`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `partition` function, this:

```
return j;
```

should be this:

```
return left+j;
```

You could have detected this bug by *testing* the function, before writing other code that called it.

Answer (score -1):

Your recursion lacks a stop criteria.

Comment: Yes it does.  When right==index+1 and index==left there will be no recursive calls.